# Creating System Compute Profile

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm trying to do some testing with Cloud Data Fusion, however, I'm receiving issues with connections when running my pipelines. I've come to understand that it is using the default network, and I would like to change my System Compute Profile over to a different network.

The problem is, I don't have the option to create a new System Compute Profile (The option doesn't show up under the Configuration tab). How can I go about getting the correct access to create a new compute profile? I have the role of Data Fusion Admin.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a new compute profile is only available in Data Fusion Enterprise edition. In the basic edition, only the default compute profile can be used. But you can customize the profile when you run the pipeline. To do that:

1. Go to the pipeline page
2. Click on Configure, in the Compute config, click Customize
3. This will pop up the settings for the profile, in General Settings, you can set the value for the network.

[image: This is a screenshot on where to customize the network value]

Answer (score 1):

Just an update on this thread for future viewer. Custom profile can be created in Cloud data fusion Version 6.2.2 (Basic)

[image]